# How can I record Stereo in iOS 14 Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, avaudiosession, ios14, avaudiorecorder

How can I record Stereo in iOS 14 Objective C

here is my code I don't now how I will add **AVAudioSessionPolarPatternStere**o to my code
I found the simple code for Swift but I need to add in my objective c code

```
    AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    const AVAudioSessionPolarPattern AVAudioSessionPolarPatternStereo;
        
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
    
    NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
```

Comment: this is your obj-c code right ?

Comment: use `if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)){ [audioSession setPreferredInputOrientation:error:]; }` [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/3551725-setpreferredinputorientation?language=objc)

Comment: @OlSen here is bug for this code [audioSession setPreferredInputOrientation:AVAudioSessionPolarPatternStereo error:nil];
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'API_AVAILABLE(ios(14.0)) const AVAudioSessionPolarPattern' (aka 'NSString *const') to parameter of type 'AVAudioStereoOrientation' (aka 'enum AVAudioStereoOrientation')

Comment: check your given Enum.. take one of those.. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiostereoorientation?language=objc)

Comment: can you add some code to my simple code please because I can't understand this code